# javascript for hidden element by filter

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page in which I have the following structure:

```
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<div class="tabella">
    <div class="rigaHead"></div>

            <div class="rigaEven">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                    <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">YYY</p>
                    <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaOdd">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                    <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">YYY</p>
                    <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to display only the div tag with class RigaEven or RigaOdd
Whose tag highlighted in the image as text equal to that part of a search field...
[image]
How could I do?

Comment: are you fine with a JQuery solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I keep reading this, and I'm struggling too understand what your after.  What search field are we talking about?  I can see you have a class="what" highlighted above, are you after filtering out all the rigaEven/Odd where the "who" class has the text = "text from some search input"?

Comment: Can you please use the snippet ? or jsfiddle

Comment: I wouldn't even give the option jsfiddle, snippet all the way.

Comment: I have editated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function search(what){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".rigaEven, .rigaOdd");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length;i++){
      var v = elements[i];
      if(what.length == 0 || v.querySelector(".what").textContent.indexOf(what) != -1){
          v.style.display = "block";
      }else{
          v.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search what" onkeyup="search(this.value)"/></div>
<div class="rigaEven">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                    <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">XXX</p>
                    <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaOdd">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                    <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">YYY</p>
                    <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And to make the search case insensitive you can use `v.querySelector(".what").textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(what.toLowerCase())`

Comment: It's possible to do this in a web page visualizzated in android?

Comment: @Marduk Yes, it should work on mobile devices but it depends on the browser used. Here you can see which browsers support the `querySelectorAll(...)` function http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorAll

Comment: it's not browser is a Web View sorry

Comment: @Marduk It seems that you're trying to inject some javascript into the page via the URL. If that is the case, instead of `javascrit:search(){....}` use `javascript:(function(){....})()` (self invoking function).

Comment: @Marduk Great, I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function search() {
     var text = $('#search').val();
     $( "p").css( "text-decoration", "none" );
     $( ".rigaEven").hide();
     $( ".rigaOdd").hide();
     
     $( ".rigaEven:contains("+text+")" ).show();
     $( ".rigaOdd:contains("+text+")" ).show();
     
     $( "p:contains("+text+")" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
     
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabella">
        <div class="rigaHead"></div>
    
                <div class="rigaEven">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                        <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col2 half">
                        <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col3">
                         <p class="what">YYY</p>
                        <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="rigaOdd">
                  <div class="col1">
                        <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                        <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col2 half">
                        <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col3">
                         <p class="what">ZZZ</p>
                        <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="search" onKeyUp="search()" />
```

Comment: there are possibility to hide element only in case the text is exactly like $('#search').val()?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but, I think you want to show related div according to a search result, here you are:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input_button").on("click", function() {
    $(".rigaEven").hide();
    $(".rigaOdd").hide();
    var value = $("#input_text").val();
    if (value != null && value != "") {
      if ($(".rigaEven .col1 .room").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaEven .col1 .where").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaEven .col2 .half .when").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaEven .col3 .what").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaEven .col3 .who").text().indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        $(".rigaEven").show();
      } else if ($(".rigaOdd .col1 .room").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaOdd .col1 .where").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaOdd .col2 .half .when").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaOdd .col3 .what").text().indexOf(value) >= 0
           ||$(".rigaOdd .col3 .who").text().indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        $(".rigaOdd").show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rigaEven {
  display: none;
}
.rigaOdd {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search"><input type="text" id="input_text" /><input type="button" id="input_button" value="search" /></div>
<div class="tabella">
    <div class="rigaHead">

            <div class="rigaEven">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class='room'>XXX</p>
                    <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">YYY</p>
                    <p class="who">DR</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaOdd">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class='room'>ZZZ</p>
                    <p class='where'>WHERE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class='when'>09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">TTT</p>
                    <p class="who">PROFESSOR</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```